# What's the difference between the constructor of JScrollPane and its add method when use JTable class?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am learning JTable class these days, I want to show the table header in a JFrame.

when my code like this

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); //table had been constucted;
```

all is right; but

when my code like this

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.add(table);
```

when I run the program, I can't see any data in the JFrame;

I hope to find something by reading the source code of JScrollPane and reading Java SE API document,but I didn't get pleased answer. All I know is add is inherit from Container while the constructor of JScorllPane has different achieve. but I can't understand why. :(

can you help me ? thanks very much!

ps:This is the first ask question on StackOverflow. I am a chinese student and my english is poor. if there something wrong I beg your pardon. 3ks again.

Answer (score 6):

The constructor doesn't add the JTable to the JScrollPane but rather to its viewport's view.

So this:

```
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(jTable); // (1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();  // (2)
scrollpane.setViewportView(jTable);  // (3)
```

So note that the constructor call on line (1) above doesn't add the JTable to the JScrollPane component itself, since if it did, it would replace its viewport rendering the JScrollPane inoperable. Instead the constructor adds the component to its JViewport.

Comment: :) Thank you very much! I got your meaning and know how to do.